# Issue while trying to filter records in spark dataframe column which has single quotes

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, filter, apache-spark-sql

I have spark dataframe df1. I want to filter based on `failed_rules` column which has single quotes. I tried below code but getting error.

import spark.implicits._

```
val columns = Seq("failed_rules","CMF_BANKRPT_IND","year")
val tupleSeq: Seq[(String, String, Int)] = Seq(("`name: isComplete,args:{column: cmf_lf_assess_num_hist,where_cond: CMF_BANKRPT_IND == 'B'}`", "B" , 1981),("`name: isComplete,Failure_Flag: Error,args:{column: cmf_lf_assess_num_hist,where_cond: CMF_BANKRPT_IND == 'B'}`", "A", 1989),("4", "John", 1991))

val df1=spark.createDataFrame(tupleSeq).toDF(columns:_*)
val extraCols = List("`name: isComplete,args:{column: cmf_lf_assess_num_hist,where_cond: CMF_BANKRPT_IND == 'B'}`")
val rules_wherecond = extraCols.filter( name => name.contains("where_cond"))

for (i <- 0 until rules_wherecond.length) {
  df1.filter(s"failed_rules == ${rules_wherecond(i)}").show(false)
}
```

Error msg:

> org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`name: isComplete,args:{column: cmf_lf_assess_num_hist,where_cond: CMF_BANKRPT_IND == 'B'}`' given input columns: [failed_rules, CMF_BANKRPT_IND, year]; line 1 pos 16;

Answer (score 0):

Seq.filter doesn't automatically parse json for you.  So your actual where condition isn't being parsed out and given to Spark, so Spark correctly complains that the filter you have given it isn't a valid column or expression.

Building filters up like this is full of other potential issues and drawbacks (like lack of multiple rules or auditing etc.), it may be worth looking at [Quality](https://sparkutils.github.io/quality/latest/getting_started/a_first_rulesuite/) for ideas alone but the core issue you have seems to be parsing the json before using filter.

Answer (score 0):

Explicit separation of column name and filtering value can help:

```
df1.filter($"failed_rules" === rules_wherecond(i)).show(false)
```